# Prove that linear system has no solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ is a matrix $4\times3$, $rank(A)=3$ 
Also known that all elements of $A$ are nonzero values, $a_{ij}\neq0$
$c_i$ columns of $A$ ,$A=[c_1;c_2;c_3]$

$F$ is a diagonal matrix $4\times4$, all the diagonal values are different.

Prove that the following system has no solution for $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$: 
$Ax=Fc_3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry that I wrote that $\boldsymbol F\mathbf c_3$ was in the vector space of $\mathbf c_3$.

I came up with

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3\\
2&4&5\\
3&8&6\\
4&5&4\\
\end{bmatrix}\mathbf x=
\begin{bmatrix}
2&0&0&0\\
0&11/5&0&0\\
0&0&17/6&0\\
0&0&0&13/4
\end{bmatrix}\mathbf c_3$$

which is a system where $\boldsymbol A$ and $\boldsymbol F$ fulfill the requisites and there is a $\mathbf x=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb R^3$ that solves the system.